# File Last time opened in Windows

Tags: c, winapi

I'm actually working on a mini-project to determine the last date when the file was opened.

My question is how to determine the last date when the file was opened in C under Windows.
I just need some hints about that.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Windows solution, call the GetFileAttributesEx function to find out that information. Alternatively your C runtime most likely will supply a stat function that can retrieve the information.

Answer (score 1):

There are two such dates in Windows, accessible via the [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function: The Last Write Time (which only tracks files opened for writing) and the Last Access Time which tracks both reads and writes.

Unfortunately, there is a performance option somewhere in the Registry that skips updating the last access date, and I think it's enabled by default in the latest Windows versions. :-(

Comment: The documentation for [`GetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320.aspx) states: *Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: Last access time is updated on NTFS volumes by default.* Also keep in mind: [The NTFS file system delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to 1 hour after the last access.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, so we now know it's disabled by default from 2008/Vista onwards.